# Как добавить пункт контекстного меню в Win 10

Tags: windows, консоль, windows-10, реестр

Сделал простой .reg файл

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\apk_auto_file\shell\Build setup\] 
"MUIVerb"="Установить билд..."
"Icon"="imageres.dll,25"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\apk_auto_file\shell\Build setup\command\]
@="cmd.exe \"%1\" /S /K adb install -r \"%1\" "
```

он работает для Win 7, но для win 10 ничего не происходит, нужный пункт меню не добавляется. 
Что мне нужно, по нажатию правой кнопкой на apk файл можно выбрать пункт меню, который откроет консоль с переданными мной аргументами.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы пункт меню появился у apk файлов, нужно добавить ссылку на apk_auto_file в реестре:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.apk]
@="apk_auto_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\apk_auto_file\shell\Build setup\] 
"MUIVerb"="”становить билд..."
"Icon"="imageres.dll,25"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\apk_auto_file\shell\Build setup\command\]
@="cmd.exe \"%1\" /S /K adb install -r \"%1\" "
```

Так же для создания/редактирования расширении и пунктов меню к ним, удобней использовать [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html)

Comment: Может, хоть какое-то пояснение добавите?